# How to move to the end of column

Tags: vim

For example, in this situation :

```
>    aaa
>    bbb
>    ccc
>    ddd
>
>    eee
>    ...
```

If my cursor is on the second b, what is the fastest way to go on the second d? 
I currently go to the empty line with }, then j^ and 2l...

Comment: This is a general question... I'm not often in this exact situation^^

Comment: Do you actually have the `>    ` too?

Comment: No, no, I just wanted to show this is not the beginning of the line

Comment: So, yes, you have stuff before that column. Ok

Comment: `/d<CR>` is a perfectly valid solution to your problem. Another one would be `}B`.

Comment: @romainl Except `}` doesn't take you there (this was the whole point of my comments requresing clarification).

Comment: @romainl No, my question is "How to move to the end of column", this is just an example. }B is a bit better than my current solution, thx... But I'm sure VIM got something above

Comment: @odessos Consider using a script like [CountJump](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) to define your own motion mappings

Comment: I apologize... I've done a mistake in my question... This is the 2nd d

Comment: odessos, does `2gj` work for you with that edit?

Comment: Yes, it works in this exact situation... But I need this move for all sizes of column

Comment: how about EasyMotion?

Answer (score 0):

There's no general answer to this question, a lot depends on context (which your artificial example lacks), and you also have to consider that a sequence with more keypresses that you instantly remember is quicker than the optimal sequence that you have to remember first, or even backtrack because of a wrong motion.

If the actual block is longer, `}Bl` is a good general choice.

With my [JumpToVerticalOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4841), you could use `]Vd` (jump vertically to next `d`).

Answer (score 0):

**Update** After the question was changed: <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> would do it

---

*Old answer:*

Indeed, I'd use `:se relativenumber` and just `3j` or similar. However, I just found this:

- https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim

Which might just be what you like:

[image]

It could be like `vic` and then `o` to get to either end

Comment: I had thought of that plugin, too. Unfortunately, it only provides text objects, no motions. And to get to the first `d`, you'd need `vic<Esc>b`

Comment: @IngoKarkat I'll certainly checkout your solution once, but for me  `vic<Esc>b` is not bad. I find that productivity is not so much hampered by an extra keystroke here and there, rather by a lack of predictable/"absolute" addressing. As long as the primitives are robust I like it (I think the myth that Vim is about saving keystrokes is often overrated)